# Suggestion of a book available in pdf, to learn Lebesgue integration.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I would want a recomendation for a book available as a pdf from where I can learn more about Lebesgue integration. I am going to study a course in probability theory and it was suggested that one is familiar with Lebesgueintegration. I would say that the level of the content should be on "normal", nothing to "hardcore". I want to understand the concept and be able to apply it.

Comment: Two words. Lebesgue integration. The book I learned from was the first three chapters of Royden's "Real Analysis."

Comment: Thanks, in Swedish it is one word. @AlfredYerger

Comment: Do yourself a favor: spend 25 dollars on a used copy of this book https://www.amazon.com/Lebesgue-Integration-Euclidean-Bartlett-Mathematics/dp/0763717088 .

Answer (score 2):

There's https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf from an author with considerable reputation.  However, I would personally recommend reading first the final chapter of Baby Rudin including doing its exercises. A used copy is available on amazon.co.uk right now for £9.45 plus shipping.

Comment: Are you referring to https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf ?

Comment: The link in your comment refers to a pdf of Baby Rudin.  Unless there is some wrinkle of Icelandic copyright law I don't understand, I believe it is a pirate edition.